# Using forms with non-string objects

Tags: django, django-forms

I have pretty complicated form items ;)

Here's my view for serving my form:

```
def view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = forms.ProfileEditForm(request.POST)
    else:
        form = forms.ProfileEditForm(initial={'country': request.user.profile.country})

    return direct_to_template(request, "name/of/template.html", 
            {"form": form, "countries": Country.objects.all()})
```

Here's what the country model looks like:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    iso2 = models.CharField()
    iso3 = models.CharField()
    name = models.CharField()
```

Here's what my form's clean() method looks like (highly simplified):

```
def clean(self):
    self.cleaned_data['country'] = Country.objects.get(iso2=self.cleaned_data['country'])
    return self.cleaned_data
```

Here's how I'm rendering it in a template:

```
<select name="country"{% if form.country.value %} data-initialvalue="{{form.country.value.iso2}}"{% endif %}>
    {% for country in countries %}
    <option value="{{country.iso2}}"{% if country.iso2==form.country.value.iso2 %} selected{% endif %}>{{country.name}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

However, I'm noticing that what actually ends up being delivered to my template isn't a `Country` object, but a string of my input data, such as "US". When I initially render my template with the initial data, things look fine, but when validation fails, things get messed up. What should I do, and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) for your `country` field.

And don't forget to define `__unicode__` method of the model.

Comment: Actually, for my current setup ModelChoiceField won't give me exactly what I need. I'm not using the PKs to pass around the value, as I need to use the two-letter country code when passing the values.

Comment: @TK Kocheran And why not to use your two-letter country code as pk?

Comment: ...because I'm already using my PK as the UN assigned country code for each country.

Comment: @TK Kocheran  I don't think I understand well your task. Why can't you use pk for `select`'s value?

Comment: By looking at the [source](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/fields.py), I think there's a way it would work... thanks for the tip!